# How to read a XML API with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I am learning PHP and need to know how to get the elements in following XML API into an Array. I tried with simplexml_load_file() function. But it gave me an error.

Here are my code.

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://static.cricinfo.com/rss/livescores.xml");

foreach($xml->getElementsByTagName('item') as $match)
{
    echo $match->getAttribute('title'), "\n";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the following code for it.

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://static.cricinfo.com/rss/livescores.xml");
$channel_info = $xml->channel;
$totalRecords = count($channel_info->item);
for ($i=0; $i < $totalRecords; $i++) { 
    echo $channel_info->item[$i]->title . '<br/>';
}
```

I hope it will work for you.

Thank you.

Comment: By all means.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you do this:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://static.cricinfo.com/rss/livescores.xml");
echo '<pre>';
print_r($xml);
echo '</pre>';
```

You get a more human readable structure like this:

> SimpleXMLElement Object (
>       [@attributes] => Array
>           (
>               [version] => 2.0
>           )
>
> ```
> [channel] => SimpleXMLElement Object
>     (
>         [title] => Cricinfo Live Scores
>         [ttl] => 2
>         [link] => http://www.cricinfo.com
>         [description] => Latest scores from Cricinfo
>         [copyright] => (c)Cricinfo
>         [language] => en-gb
>         [pubDate] => Sun, 20 Dec 2015 09:55:01 +0000
>         [item] => Array
>             (
>                 [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
>                     (
>                         [title] => Lions 214/10 &  316/8  v Dolphins 137/2 &  141/10 *
>                         [link] => http://www.cricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/851997.html?CMP=OTC-RSS 
>                         [description] => Lions 214/10 &  316/8  v Dolphins 137/2 &  141/10 *
>                         [guid] => http://www.cricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/851997.html
>                     )
>
>                 [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
>                     (
>                         [title] => Titans 369/10 &  171/10  v Warriors 204/5 &  209/10 *
>                         [link] => http://www.cricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/852039.html?CMP=OTC-RSS 
>                         [description] => Titans 369/10 &  171/10  v Warriors 204/5 &  209/10 *
>                         [guid] => http://www.cricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/852039.html
>                     )
>
>                 [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
>                     (
>                         [title] => New Zealand 142/5 &  237/10 * v Sri Lanka 292/10 &  133/10 
>                         [link] => http://www.cricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/914205.html?CMP=OTC-RSS 
>                         [description] => New Zealand 142/5 &  237/10 * v Sri Lanka 292/10 &  133/10 
>                         [guid] => http://www.cricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/914205.html
>                     )
> ```
>
> etc...

And so you can see the information you want as a $match is in:
channel->item

So:

```
foreach($xml->channel->item as $match) {
    print_r($match);
    echo '<hr><br>';
}
```

Will give you an overview of the matches from the xml url.
You can then use the child elements like this for example:

```
foreach($xml->channel->item as $match) {
    echo $match->title;
    echo '<hr><br>';
}
```